# install4j - Windows - Service launcher not working, flashes but provides no output and no error

Tags: windows, install4j

I'm evaluating install4j to use it to run a Jetty service on Windows.

When I build the Install4j installer, it works fine when I use the "Console" launcher. I click on my "App.exe" and the service starts as expected.

But when I build the Install4j launcher with "Service" launcher, it installs seemingly successfully. But when I launch the "App.exe" it just flashes a console and then does nothing.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a service executable from the command line, start it with the `/run` argument.

Service executables are not meant to be executed directly without arguments, they are called by the service manager. In install4j, you install them with an "Install a service" action.

Comment: Yep that's what I was missing. Thanks.